# Preventing double form submission via JS, but on event is not binding to a modal element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to prevent users from submitting a form twice (adding to cart). The problem I am running into is that my form is on a modal (Twitter Bootstrap).

**cart.js.coffee**

```
preventMultipleSubmit = ->
  $(".edit_offer input[type=\"submit\"]").on "click", () ->
    $(this).attr "disabled", "disabled"

$(document).ready(preventMultipleSubmit)
$(document).on("page:load", preventMultipleSubmit)
```

The code above works if I don't load the form up in a modal. **How do I attach the on click event to the submit button that exists in a modal?** I am also using Turbolinks if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, not so elegant, but it works. Let me know if you guys know how to simplify this:

```
preventMultipleSubmit = ->
  $(".edit_offer").on "submit", () ->
     $(this).find("input[type=\"submit\"]").attr "disabled", "disabled"

  $("#offerModal").on "shown.bs.modal", ->
    $(".edit_offer").on "submit", () ->
      $(this).find("input[type=\"submit\"]").attr "disabled", "disabled"
```